# Windows 10 Installation made Ubuntu unbootable

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

So since installing Windows 10 onto my computer I can't use Ubuntu anymore. 
Whenever I go into the boot menu and select the drive with Ubuntu on it the only thing I get is a black screen and a blinking cursor. No matter how long I wait the screen doesn't change. 
I installed both OSs on separate drives and now in Windows don't even see my Ubuntu drive in the file explorer anymore. In the disk management window it is still there, without a filesystem tough.

I would appreciate every help to get back my Ubuntu back, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Windows will always overwrite Ubuntu GRUB Boot Manager.
The only way is to boot into an Ubuntu Live CD and repair the GRUB from there. Please, proceed with caution while dealing with disk drives and you will be alright running both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: So now I have to boot Ubuntu from the USB again? And how do I have to repair the GRUB?

Comment: Yes, there are detailed tutorials available. See this askubuntu thread for more information. https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot, you saved my day :)